# Adding a popup to features in a leaflet.vectorgrid layer

Tags: leaflet, popup, vector-tiles, maptiler

I am loading a tile set from MapTiler to my leaflet map. I have no trouble styling each feature in the tile set. I can set each feature to the appropriate color.

I would like to also add a popup to each of the features. Is this possible? How? Where is the documentation that explains this?

```
const FOO_TILES_PBF_URL =  "https://api.maptiler.com/tiles/<tileset_identifier>/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf?key=<my_maptiler_key>";

  function getColorFromRedBlueRange(d) {
    return d == 8
      ? {
          fillColor: "yellow",
          fillOpacity: 0.7,
          color: "yellow",
          fill: true,
          weight: 1.5
        }
      : d == 7
      ? {
          fillColor: "red",
          fillOpacity: 0.7,
          color: "red",
          fill: true,
          weight: 1.5
        }
      : {
          fillColor: "black",
          fillOpacity: 0.7,
          color: "black",
          fill: true,
          weight: 1.5
        };

var FooTileOptions= {
    interactive: true,
    vectorTileLayerStyles: {
      LayerName: properties => {
        return getColorFromRedBlueRange(
          properties.foo_variable]
        );
      }
    }
  };

  var fooLayer= L.vectorGrid.protobuf(
    FOO_TILES_PBF_URL,
    FooTileOptions
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your "fooLayer" with something like this:

```
var fooLayer=L.vectorGrid.protobuf(FOO_TILES_PBF_URL, FooTileOptions).on('click', function (e) { 
    L.popup()
    .setContent(e.layer.properties.foo_variable)
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .openOn(map)
});
```